# Max execution time of 7200 exceeded

Tags: php, wamp, php.ini

I am using wamp to setup my local server.

I am running a script which may take days to be completed.

Although I have set `php.ini` settings to high numbers but after 7200 seconds still get the exceeded error message.

I have set `max_execution_time=42700` and other settings to a high number as well.

Any Help or suggestion?

Comment: For something that is going to run for a long time run it from the command line which does not impose any limits.

Comment: It can't be done because I am using a wordpress plugin to import some data from one server to another. I must use wordpress plugin page to import.

Comment: Set the time-limit to infinite with `max_execution_time=0`, or add in `php.ini` the line `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);`, or better add for only one script `set_time_limit(0);`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer add `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);` to php.ini?
I will try your answer. I will keep you informed if it does or doesn't work.

Comment: it didn't work :(

Comment: You cannot reliably run long jobs from an HTTP request. If you don’t have a background scheduler available you must instead split the work. If you are unable to, that’s it. It will never work.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following steps:

1. If you can modify **php.ini**, find the line that reads (or create a new one), with the command:
   **max_execution_time = 0**
2. If you can't modify php.ini, you can try to change the code in your **.htaccess** with the command:
   **php_value max_execution_time 0**
3. You can also modify the **php** page you are launching your script from by adding the following as the first line: **set_time_limit(0);**
4. Verify that the change worked by creating a test php page, with the following command:
   **phpinfo();**
   The **Local Value** column should display the new setting. If it doesn't, maybe some other plugin is modifying the value, and because of that, your script is getting terminated.

Comment: I have tested all of those options but maybe you are right, another plugin overwriting the default value.

I couldn't fix it so import took 2 days to be done! 

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I had experienced this issue as well importing 27 million records.   I had been setting the max execution code at the top of the file an it kept getting reset to 7200.   I issue was in the include header being included after I set the execution code.  after updating my header the issue went away

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1145764)